# Module pattern usage with event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

My query is regarding efficient usage of *JavaScript Module Patterns*. Below is a **simplified** module from my code. I want to re-factor it into modules. The modules would have a few 100 LOC each.

**Question :** Which of the methods 1 vs 2 vs 3 are better? In *method 1*, is it a waste to create a new object each time the mouse hovers over the element? Please feel free to critique / suggest an alternate implementation.

**Context :** I have a few dozen elements with `.myclass` attribute that need occasional event handling over the lifetime of the web page.

```
(function ($) {

  var MyModule = function (element) {
      this.element = element
  }

  MyModule.prototype.color1 = function () {
      $(this.element).css('backgroundColor', '#aaa');
  }

  MyModule.prototype.color2 = function () {
      $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#aaa');
  }

  //Event handlers for MyModule 
  $('#mydiv').on('mouseenter', '.myclass', function(evt) {
      //Method 1
      var myMod = new MyModule(this);
      myMod.color1();

      //Method 2
      MyModule.prototype.color2.call(this)          
  });

  $('body').on('mouseleave', function(evt) {...});


})(jQuery);
```

---

**Update**

I would like to understand what's an efficient way to reference the module inside it's event handlers, if I were to stick with module pattern. Hence eliminating the object literal method. This is creating confusion. I'd prefer to learn the above for pedagogical reasons rather than simplify it to use an object literal.

<strike>Alternate implementation using object literal</strike>

```
... Code Removed ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prototyping is one of the great things about javascript, but here you're using it totally wrong, there's no need for this pattern to do something as simple as

```
jQuery(function($) {

    $('#mydiv').on({
        mouseenter: function(evt) {
            $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#aaa');
        },
        mouseleave: function(evt) {

        }
    }, '.myclass');

});
```

creating a new instance of an object to get an element and change it's color is not really something you should have to do.

Comment: Agreed. However this is a simplified version of the code. In reality, it's a few thousand lines and I want to re-factor it into modules. Each module is a few 100 lines and has a dozen methods. Keeping that & maintainability / modularity in mind, what would you suggest?

Comment: I would suggest staying away from prototypes if you don't actually need a new instance of a class but are just using it to seperate out code, and instead factor the code into blocks and functions, and maybe even using literals if it fits with what you're doing.

Comment: Could you suggest a use case by extending the above example where actually having a new instance of class would be useful?

Comment: @buffer - I really can't think of any good reasons to using that pattern with jQuery in this way. jQuery has it's own way of doing this with `$.fn` and plugins, so it had to be something pretty darn special to use prototypes.

Comment: I leveraged some of the coding style from Bootstrap modal dialog : [example](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js).

Comment: They are really pretty much the same, I tend to use the first one, passing constants to the constructor itself.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be an assumption in your examples that you need to create some MyModule object or namespace when you're using the module pattern. That is incorrect, in my opinion.

In your vastly simplified examples, there's no need for the created MyModule to live outside the IIFE, because you don't return the MyModule object outside nor do you assign it to some global namespace. But crucially, that's the motivation for choosing between alternatives 1, 2, & 3. Whether you need to create an instance on each invocation, whether you can get away with creating just a singleton instance, or whether you can just assign a function in the closure, depends on what the event handler actually needs to do -- not on some theoretical discussion of Module Pattern best practices. None of the alternatives you mentioned have any impact on the code's modularizability.

In the given example as written, there's a fourth alternative that is more efficient that the three you mentioned

```
(function ($) {
  var MyModule = {
    color : function (evt) {
      // I'm not sure whether you want this or evt.target
      $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#aaa');
    }  
  }

  //Event handlers for MyModule 
  $('#mydiv').on('mouseenter', '.myclass', MyModule.color);
})(jQuery);
```

You don't have to create a new function instance handler for each DOM element you attach to. The event information is automatically passed to the function, and `this` is the DOM element that the handler is attached to. Both this information is passed to the handler by jQuery on, because that's how raw browser JavaScript handles events. If that is all the information your handler needs to do its job, then you only need a single instance of your handler.

Comment: I'm following the code pattern used by Bootstrap here : https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/blob/master/js/modal.js (without making a jQuery plugin). I understand that the current example can be easily simplified to an object literal. However I'm trying to understand, what's an efficient way to reference the module inside it's event handlers? If I were to stick with module pattern. I'll probably eliminate method 3 for pedagogical reasons.

Comment: What's most efficient depends on what you need to do -- the right answer is situational and there's no universal answer. There are some general principles, but the principles have lots of exceptions.